# What host, port to use to connect to a SQL server management studio DB in studio 3T

Tags: mongodb, sql-server-express, studio3t

What I am trying to do is migrate data from a mongoDB to a SQL express DB.

I have Microsoft SQL server management studio 18 installed. 
I also have Studio 3T installed (the trial).

I am trying to use the SQL migration function (mongoDB -> SQL) but I am at a loss for what I should put in to connect to the local database I made in management studio to test this functionality. I have an empty database called testdb.

What host and port should I use?

When I login on management studio this is simply my computer name followed by \SQLEXPRESS. For authentication it uses windows authentication (I assume this is my login name and password for my computer).

I have tried filling this host, or changing my computer name with localhost, 127.0.0.1, nothing. The port is automatically put to 1433 when I select SQL server as the SQL type.

Here is a screenshot of the connection prompt.

[image: Screenshot of the prompt]

Whatever I fill in there, I always get an error when I check the connection. The error is `Unknown server host name` so I think it can not find the Sql express server/DB.